# sequilize: How to get record with createdat greater than 1 hour

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am new in sequelize, and I don't know how to get the records with createdAt column less than 1 hours with the current date and here is my code :

```
models.Trip.findAll({
    where: {
      createdAt: {
        $gt:  -------> createdAt <= 1 hour with current date
      }
    },
    include: [
      models.User,
      models.Vehicle,
    ],
  })
```

How to do that, please help me. Thanks!

Comment: $gt : date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+1 hour'))

Comment: ^ that's PHP, the question is regarding Javascript

Comment: this is nodejs server

Comment: I have same kind of issue.
Please check https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377736/how-to-get-records-updated-at-10-hours-using-sequelize-nodejs-postgresql

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 10):

Use `sequelize.literal()` to query based on the database server time.

Using the server:

```js
created_at: {
  [Op.gt]: sequelize.literal("NOW() - INTERVAL '24 HOURS'")),
}
```

Use a `Date` object set to one hour in the past by subtracting milliseconds from `Date.now()`.

**Using [`Sequelize.Op`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators)**

```js
created_at: {
  [Op.gt]: new Date(Date.now() - (60 * 60 * 1000)),
},
```

**Using old style [operator aliases](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators-aliases):**

```js
created_at: {
  $gt: new Date(Date.now() - (60 * 60 * 1000)),
},
```

Comment: sorry i want the sql like this :
SELECT DATEDIFF('created_at, 'now) > 1;

Comment: but datediff not exists in postgres, could you suggest for me other function

Comment: Do you specifically need to use the time from the database? Does the app server not suffice?

Comment: I want to get the records with createdAt greater than 1 hour compared with itself
for example `SELECT DATEDIFF('created_at, 'now) > 1;`

Comment: or just a subtraction 2 days (now and createdAt) and result will be hours

Comment: here is the correct sql : `select EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM current_timestamp - "createdAt")/3600, "createdAt", now() FROM "Trips"`, can you help me apply this to sequelize

Comment: Greate Job! Thanks

Comment: Is there a solution for this?

Comment: @arunwebber you mean other than what is in the answer? Not sure what you are looking for...